# How does Cox proportional hazards model deal with time-dependent variables?

Tags: r, survival, time-varying-covariate

When considering time dependent data in survival analysis, you have multiple start-stop times for an individual subject with measurements for the covariates.  If each season has a different size (for example: repr=90 days,post_r=5,winter=23), the probability of an individual dying in repr it's largest.

How does the Cox model deal with different sizes of time intervals?

I'm using `coxph()` in R. Here's an example:

```
subject | start   | stop   | event  | season    |  
--------+---------+--------+--------+-----------+  
1       | 1       | 90     | 0      | repr      |  
1       | 90      | 95     | 0      | post-r    |  
1       | 95      | 118    | 1      | winter    |  
2       | 1       | 23     | 0      | winter    |  
2       | 23      | 113    | 0      | repr      |  
2       | 113     | 118    | 0      | post-r    |  
2       | 118     | 141    | 1      | winter    |
```

Comment: This is a broad question. The cox model evaluates the covariable values at all time points at which events occur. Longer intervals should have, all other things equal, a higher chance of containing more time points at which events occur, and therefore the covariable values associated with them a higher influence on the estimated hazard ratio.

Comment: Basically, the results will always be biased?

Comment: Quite the opposite. Using only the baseline values can introduce bias if your predictor changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

Within categories of the covariates there will be a calculation of the cumulative hazard as a function of the time from beginning of the observations, summing intervals until either an event or a final censoring. As an example with your data, the "winter" intervals had two entrants with three intervals and 2 events,  first of which was at 118-95 time units for subject 1 and the second of which was at (21-1)+(141-118) units for subject 2. So the cumulative hazard function would be a step function within that covariate would rise to 50% at t=23 and 100% at t=43.